# docker-compose config does not keep references to env_files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to utilize docker-compose config feature to merge multiple compose files into one.

Here is an example

```
docker compose -f base.yml -f foo.yml -f bar.yml config --no-normalize --no-path-resolution --no-consistency --output merged.yml
```

but merged compose does not keep references to `env_file` property, instead, it exposes all environment variables and their values into `environment` property, which does not fit my use case, for example:

**base.yml**

```
...
env_file:
 - config.conf
```

**merged.yml**

```
...
environment:
 - PROP1=1
 - PROP2=2
 - PROP3=3
```

**How do I keep references to original env files? Or is there a way of merging multiple compose files that supports desired behavior?**

I tried using the following `config` command flags, but it did not yield desired result:

```
--no-normalize --no-path-resolution --no-consistency
```